# jQuery - Display message when user leaves page if they haven't scrolled to bottom

Tags: jquery, scroll

New-ish to jQuery and can't get the final piece of this code to work.  I'm trying to display a simple alert when the user leaves the page by clicking a link IF they have not seen ALL of the page content by scrolling to the bottom.

I'm not sure whether it should prevent the user from going to the next page yet, but for now I'd just like to get the piece that detects if the user has reached the bottom and make it work with the code I have.  I already have the piece that detects whether there is a scroll bar and am stuck on how to register when the user makes it to the bottom:

**jQuery:**

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var verticalScrollPresent = function() {
                return document.documentElement.scrollHeight !== document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            }

            $('#nav').click(function() {
                if (verticalScrollPresent) {
//imagining that this is where the code will go, but how can I register that the user     has scrolled to the bottom?
                        alert("There's a whole bunch of stuff you haven't seen yet!");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="nav" href="http://google.com">Next page</a>
```

Comment: Can't you simply put the link to the next page at the bottom?

Comment: This is true, but this is only the beginning of the process.  Eventually I have to make it work with links/buttons that appear in frames and I wanted to start off by making sure I got the logic and syntax of the code correct before trying it within our framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a variable to false, and when the user scrolls to the bottom, set the variable to true, check that variable when the user clicks the link:

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var beenToBottom = false;
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
            //guesstimated scrolled to bottom, adjust as neccessary
            if (($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() + 200) > $(document).height()) {
                beenToBottom = true;
            }
        });

        $('#nav').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!beenToBottom) {
                alert("There's a whole bunch of stuff you haven't seen yet!");
            }else{
                document.location.href = this.href;
            }
        });
    });
</script>​
```

Comment: Sweet!  I had tried something close to that but my syntax in the first if statement was probably wrong.  Very helpful, thank you adeneo!